# Replace seconds with time format on multiple elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime, time

I'm struggling a little bit.

I have multiple elements containing a time in seconds.

```
<p><time class="replace_time">3.232151</time></p>
<p><time class="replace_time">5.234151</time></p>
...
```

```
jQuery(".replace_time").text(function(){
        
    var d = jQuery(this).text();
    
    var h = Math.floor(d / 3600);
    var m = Math.floor(d % 3600 / 60);
    var s = Math.floor(d % 3600 % 60);

    if (h > 0) {       
        return (("0" + h).slice(-2) + ":" + ("0" + m).slice(-2) + ":" + ("0" + s).slice(-2));     
    }
        
    else {    
        return ("0" + m).slice(-2) + ":" + ("0" + s).slice(-2); 
    };
    
});
```

It's basically working but unfortunately only for the last (??) item in the DOM order  What do I overlook?

Comment: You've got to wonder why jQuery is used at all for things like this given `document.querySelectorAll(".replace_time").forEach(el => ...)` where *el.textContent* returns or replaces the text content of the element without creating multiple additional jQuery objects (or any at all).

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use the **.each** function to get every element

```
jQuery(".replace_time").each(function(){
    
    var d = jQuery(this).text();

    var h = Math.floor(d / 3600);
    var m = Math.floor(d % 3600 / 60);
    var s = Math.floor(d % 3600 % 60);

    if (h > 0) {       
        jQuery(this).text(("0" + h).slice(-2) + ":" + ("0" + m).slice(-2) + ":" + ("0" + s).slice(-2));     
    }
    
    else {    
        jQuery(this).text(("0" + m).slice(-2) + ":" + ("0" + s).slice(-2)); 
    };

});
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't replace anything anymore... 

Comment: Try to debug it a little, I still think the underlying issue is that you are not iterating over your results and accessing each one of them, are you getting correct element as d every time?

Comment: Was a stupid mistake of mine

Answer (score 0):

@ErnestasL has your answer, you need to iterate over the array returned by the initial query.

If you split out the time formatting part, the rest is pretty simple without jQuery getting in the way:

```js
// Format seconds as time HH:mm:ss
function formatTime(secs) {
  let z = n => ('0'+n).slice(-2);
  let h = Math.floor(secs / 3600);
  let m = Math.floor(secs % 3600 / 60);
  let s = Math.floor(secs % 3600 % 60);
  return `${z(h)}:${z(m)}:${z(s)}`;
}

document.querySelectorAll('.replace_time').forEach(
  el => el.textContent = formatTime(el.textContent)
);
```

```html
<p><time class="replace_time">3.232151</time></p>
<p><time class="replace_time">182735.234151</time></p>
```